# pgsql concat for number returning null

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have created a sequence like below:

```
     CREATE SEQUENCE public.shiwangini_seq
     INCREMENT BY 1
     MINVALUE 1
     MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
     START 150037
     CACHE 1
     NO CYCLE;
```

After this - I have created a function which will use this sequence to generate next value:

```
  create or replace function shiwangini_unq(out v_final_value2 bigint) as $$
  declare 
  v_seq_value bigint;
  v_shard_id bigint;
  v_final_value2 bigint ;
  begin 
  select nextval('shiwangini_seq') into v_seq_value ;
  v_shard_id := 2;
  select concat (v_seq_value , v_shard_id ) into v_final_value2 ;
  end ;
  $$ language plpgsql ;
```

Now, this function returns null whenever I call it. Like below:

```
    select shiwangini_unq();  ----null
```

I checked concat() manages type conversion itself. Even after that, in my case it's returning null. I help will be really appreciated to make it working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In `DECLARE` section remove `v_final_value2 bigint ;` it is overriding the `OUT` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver - now it's working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is, that the *variable*  `v_final_value2` overshadows your out parameter.

But all that isn't needed to begin with.

You should declare a proper return type. But you are overcomplicating things here. You can make this more efficient without PL/pgSQL and a simple SQL function:

```
create or replace function shiwangini_unq() 
  return bigint 
as $$
  select concat(nextval('shiwangini_seq'), 2)::bigint;
$$ language sql;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write this as normal SQL function (without OUT parameter) and eliminate all data conversations.

```
create or replace 
function shiwangini_unq() 
  returns bigint 
 language sql
as $$
   select 10*nextval('shiwangini_seq')+2;
$$;
```

OR just get rid of the function altogether.

```
create sequence shiwangini_seqX start with 12 increment by 10;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=793d82dc44cd848e3adefa898b397be9)

Answer (score 0):

You give the return type of your function as an input, that is the problem. The below code is working well for me if there any error please text me back.
Try this

```
create or replace function shiwangini_unq() returns bigint as $$
  declare 
  v_seq_value bigint;
  v_shard_id bigint;
  v_final_value2 bigint ;
  begin 
  select nextval('shiwangini_seq') into v_seq_value ;
  v_shard_id := 2;
  select concat (v_seq_value, v_shard_id ) into v_final_value2 ;
 return v_final_value2;
  end ;
  $$ language plpgsql ;
```

Comment: No that is not the case. `v_final_value2` was declared as an `OUT` parameter which means it is automatically declared as part of `RETURNS` and will be returned without a `RETURN`. The issue is in the `DECLARE`  with `v_final_value2 bigint ;` as that overrides the `OUT` variable.